# How to create table rows in for loop

Tags: javascript, tablerow

I have a little issue with my *For loop* in Javascript. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("CAN_gen_1.json", function(json) {
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.messages.length; i++) {
      tr = $('<tr/>');
      var details = json.messages[i];
      for (var j = 0; j <= details.signals.length; j++) {
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].start_bit + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].comment + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].bit_length + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].factor + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].offset + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].is_big_endian + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].is_signed + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].name + "</td>");
        $('#table_1').append(tr);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I declare a table-row (tr). I use it each time I loop through my json file. The problem is that I get one single row with all the data.

I would like to cut the row in order to have a readable table.

Look at the snapshot : [image: Single Data Row].

Comment: Do an inspect to see why. You want to append to a TBODY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you're only creating one `<tr>` per table.

Create your `tr`s inside the inner loop:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("CAN_gen_1.json", function(json) {
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.messages.length; i++) {
      var details = json.messages[i];
      for (var j = 0; j <= details.signals.length; j++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].start_bit + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].comment + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].bit_length + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].factor + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].offset + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].is_big_endian + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].is_signed + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].name + "</td>");
        $('#table_1').append(tr);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This code is a bit unwieldy. I would suggest factoring out a function to create the rows. This way it's clear when they need to be created and you don't have to keep repeating `details.signals[j]`:

```
function tableRowForSignal(signal) {
  return $('<tr />')
   .append($("<td>").text(signal.start_bit));
   .append($("<td>").text(signal.comment));
   .append($("<td>").text(signal.bit_length));
   .append($("<td>").text(signal.factor));
   .append($("<td>").text(signal.offset));
   .append($("<td>").text(signal.is_big_endian));
   .append($("<td>").text(signal.is_signed));
   .append($("<td>").text(signal.name));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("CAN_gen_1.json", function(json) {
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.messages.length; i++) {
      var details = json.messages[i];
      for (var j = 0; j <= details.signals.length; j++) {
        $('#table_1').append(tableRowForSignal(details.signals[j]));
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks. Just forgot to add the return statement.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new row for **each row**

> ```
>   tr = $('<tr/>');
>   var details = json.messages[i];
>   for (var j = 0; j <= details.signals.length; j++) {
>     tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].start_bit + "</td>");
> ```

The first of these lines needs to be **inside** the loop where you create the cells that go inside it.

Comment: @mplungjan — There are two loops. The one that creates all the cells for a row is the inner loop. The first line in the quoted code is outside that inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("CAN_gen_1.json", function(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.messages.length; i++) {
      var details = json.messages[i];
      for (var j = 0; j <= details.signals.length; j++) {
        var tr = $('<tr>');
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].start_bit + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].comment + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].bit_length + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].factor + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].offset + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].is_big_endian + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].is_signed + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].name + "</td>");
        tr.append("</tr>");
        $('#table_1').append(tr);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -4):

You have to open the row before the for with

```
<tr>
```

and after all the appends you should close it with

```
</tr>
```

Comment: tr = $('<tr/>'); does that

Comment: The question is dealing with jQuery/DOM, not HTML. It works with elements, not tags (despite the abstraction). Even if this was HTML, the end tag for the `tr` element is optional!